# PBRequester failed with Error -1001 "bad URL" for Apple Maps download on simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, apple-maps

The first time I try using `geocodeAddressString:inRegion:completionHandler` after a reset of the iOS simulator I get this error:

`PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x113bba860 {NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x113bbf2b0 "bad URL"}`

This doesn't happen on the device, or on subsequent runs on the simulator (something gets cached, I'm assuming.) Does anyone know what it is or how to prevent it?

Comment: Seeing the same thing after upgrading to Xcode 5.1! I see it on subsequent runs too..

Comment: Seems to be related with iOS 7.1 Xcode 5.1 ... Hope get solved as soon as posible.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem (error on simulator but not on device) but i fixed it by cleaning the project, resetting the simulator and restarting xcode.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall your app from the iOS simulator (just like you'd do on a real device, click and hold on the app icon...)
2) Xcode > Window > Organizer > (your project) > Derived Data > Delete...
3) Rebuild and you should be good to go.
That's what worked for me.